# Finding a file path

Tags: file, path

Which method of the File class can I use to return the absolute path of a text file whose name is already mentioned in the application. In other words, the name of the file or its relative path is not to be typed in by the user.

Comment: What platform? Java? .NET? Something else?

Comment: Its not very clear what you want.  Do you already have the file name in the application?  If so how did you get it, can you not get the absolute path at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Either e.g. FileInfo.FullName in VB.Net

or I don´t understand the question...